# Someone's on a round

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

Our Principal was walking around in the school, inspecting the kids and see what they were doing(such inspections are always sudden). So our teacher said:

> Sit up straight,  Ms.X is on a round.

Is the use of "on a round" natural?

Answer (score 1):

It might or might not be the normal word in a particular school, where they might use "round", "patrol" or "tour".  "Round" is certainly the normal word for doctors in a hospital (as is "the rounds")

Your sentence reads perfectly naturally, as do these:

- Sit up straight, Ms X is **doing a round** (same meaning)
- Look busy, **Dr X is on a round** (in a hospital, where rounds are regular) Also "on the rounds", and because regular and known also "on the round"
- Note: Ms X is **around** (means only Ms X is nearby)
- Note: "round" in British drinking vocabulary has different constructions

Comment: And what about: "make the rounds"? And I couldn't find "on the round" online..

Comment: And can these be only used for doctors???

Comment: It comes down to whether this is the normal word in a given institution.  As far as I know, it's universal in hospitals (for doctors, nurses, midwives, etc) and certainly very common in other sectors.  The headmaster of my UK school would speak of "doing the rounds" or "do a round this morning"